# Azure Service bus message - how to know current delivery count?

Tags: azureservicebus

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.maxdeliverycount?view=azure-dotnet talks about max delivery count. Is there a way to know current delivery count?

We need this for testing instrumentation. We want to process the message when message is delivered to message processor in 5th attempt.

Comment: Is it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.message.deliverycount?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Devices_Client_Message_DeliveryCount  ?

Comment: Yes. [Message.DeliveryCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.message.deliverycount?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Devices_Client_Message_DeliveryCount) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

@Datha Yes, you need to look for [Message property Delivery Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.message.deliverycount?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Devices_Client_Message_DeliveryCount) to know how many times the message was tried to be consumed by your application. If you are looking for max delivery count then you need to look at the entity(queue/subscription) level property.